Every countable cover has a countable star refinement
Let $\mathcal U$ be a countable cover of a set $X$. Is is true that there is a countable cover $\mathcal V$ such that $\mathcal V^*\lesssim\mathcal U$? This is a result implied by the following Exercise 36B.5 in Willard's General Topology:


The collection $\mu'$ of all finite (countable) covers of a set $X$ is a base for a uniformity on $X$, whose uniform topology is the discrete topology. [Use partitions; see 36A.]


For a finite cover $\mathcal U=\{U_1,\dots,U_n\}$, let
$$\mathcal V=\{A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n\colon A_i=U_i\text{ or }X\setminus U_i\}.$$
Then clearly $\mathcal V$ is disjoint, covers $X$, and star-refines $\mathcal U$. But this doesn't apply to countable covers $\mathcal U=\{U_1,U_2,\dots\}$ since $\mathcal V=\{\bigcap_{i=1}^
\infty A_i\colon A_i=U_i\text{ or }X\setminus U_i\}$ would then be uncountable.
The exercise 36A is about existence of a finest partition $P(\mathcal U)$ refined by a given cover $\mathcal U$. I believe this can be obtained by repeatedly taking star-closures:
$$P(\mathcal U)=\{U\cup\operatorname{St}(U,\mathcal U)\cup\cdots\colon U\in\mathcal U\}$$
But I'm not sure if 36A is used to show the result in question, or something else in the exercise. Any help is appreciated!

Why would $\mathcal V$ be uncountable if $\mathcal U$ is countable?

@AlessandroCodenotti Let $f: P(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathcal{V}$ with $f: S \mapsto \left(\bigcap_{i \in S} U_i \right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N} \setminus S} X \setminus U_i \right)$.  It is a bijection.

I thought I figured it out, but it turns out I didn't. I'll edit the post and add a definition of $\mathcal V$ in the countable case.

@Noiril are you taking infinite intersections of members of $\mathcal U$ (or their complements) to construct $\mathcal V$ or only finite ones?

@AlessandroCodenotti I'm taking infinite intersections; additionally, in $A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots$, no $A_i$ equals $X$ unless $U_i=\varnothing\text{ or }X$. I'll re-edit the post to change the notation to be more precise.
